# How to get absolute path from Path in HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I'm pretty much new to HDFS and faced the following problem: `org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path` does not have a method something like `getAbsolutePath` which would return `String`.

The `toString` method is not documented properly so is it reliable to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path should return the full path. Yeah the toString method has barely any documentation but it works like it should!

Perhaps this could work too:

```
Path p = fs.getFileStatus(new Path(".")).getPath(); 
URI(p.toString()).getPath();
```

Reference: http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Is-there-a-way-to-get-an-absolute-HDFS-path-td3820562.html

Answer (score 3):

Try below hdfs command :

```
hdfs getconf -confKey fs.defaultFS
```

Answer (score 2):

As you stated, it may not be a good idea to rely on "toString". What if the definition of toString changes in the future.

I think it is better to do something like

```
path.toURI().getRawPath()
```